# 2 asp project working together

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have proj1 and proj2. in proj1 I have some functions that I need to use in proj2. proj1 is Dynamic Library and proj2 is executable. when I'm adding the proj1.dll to proj2 I'm getting the folowing message: "A custon build rule to build files with extension ".dll" coulp not be found...."
How can I build the rule correctly? 
There is other way to use proj1 function in proj2?

Comment: Retagged since the originals made no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor your code and place reusable functions into another class library for consumption by both proj1 and proj2.